# Rolling Average improvements

Tags: java

I have created a class intended to average the previous few data points submitted. It is able to change in size and has a feature to bypass the average without affecting the data contained therein. Are there any improvements I could make, or any exceptions thrown in certain situations that I haven't thought of?

```
public class RollingAverage {

    private double[] data;
    private boolean bypass = false;

    public RollingAverage(int size) {
        if (size == 1) {
            bypass = true;
        }

        data = new double[size];
        Arrays.fill(data, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    }

    /**
     * Adds a data point to the rolling average
     *
     * @param newData
     * @return the new average
     */
    public double addData(double newData) {
        if (bypass) {
            return newData;
        }
        boolean full = true;
        for (double point : data) {
            if (point == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
                full = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (full) {
            int j = 0;
            while (j < data.length - 1) {
                data[j++] = data[j];
            }
            data[0] = newData;

            int sum = 0;
            for (double point : data) {
                sum += point;
            }
            return sum / data.length;
        } else {
            double sum = newData;
            int j = 0;
            while (data[j] != Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
                sum += data[j++];
            }
            data[j] = newData;
            return sum / (j + 1);
        }
    }

    public void changeSize(int size) {
        if (size == data.length) {
            return;
        }

        if (size == 1) {
            bypass = true;
        }

        double[] oldData = data;
        data = new double[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (i < oldData.length) {
                data[i] = oldData[i];
            } else {
                data[i] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            }
        }
    }

    public void setBypass(boolean bypass) {
        this.bypass = bypass;
    }

    public void clear() {
        Arrays.fill(data, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    }

    public int getAverage() {
        return (int) getAverageDouble();
    }

    public double getAverageDouble() {
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (double point : data) {
            if (point != Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
                sum += point;
                count++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return sum / count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of java.util.ArrayList, or are you required to use an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My thoughts:

- IllegalArgumentException when entering size < 1 (point made by palacsint)
- Somehow remedy the situation when no data exists (either IllegalStateException or return 0?)
- You are using an int to calculate the sum of longs in getAverageDouble(), this will cause precisions errors and potentially completely wrong results if sum wraps

Overall though I think you should consider using a different, queue-like, data structure (i.e. LinkedList) to hold your data. This should really reduce the complexity of the code. It could actually *increase* performance as you no longer have to shift elements when the array is full or determine whether the array is full or not at each add (though I would worry about readability first and performance only if needed).

Answer (score 5):

1. On `new RollingAverage(-1)` it throws a `NegativeArraySizeException`. An `IllegalArgumentException` with a proper message would be better here since clients should not know that you are using arrays in the implementation.
2. On `new RollingAverageImpl(1).getAverage()` it throws an `ArithmeticExpression`. What about an `IllegalStateException` here?
3. If you are using `Integer.MIN_VALUE` as a special marker value the `addData` method should not accept it. Just throw an `IllegalArgumentException`. (I'd consider using `Double.NaN` here as a named constant, like `EMPTY_DATA` or just `EMPTY`.)
4. Comparing doubles with integers (like `point == Integer.MIN_VALUE`) might not be precise. See: [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)
5. If you calculate the new average after every `addData` call maybe you should cache it and use the cached value in the  `getAverageDouble` method.
6. Actually, I'd cache the `sum` too, and in the `addData` subtract the old value from the `sum` (if the array is full) and add the `newData` to it, then divide it by the number of elements. Maybe there are better algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

When using double, Double.NaN is probably a better flag than Integer.MIN_VALUE.

If you really want to use an array based structure, you would probably be better off with a [Circular Buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer)

I would cache the `sum`, as @palacsint suggested. This will reduce recalculating the new average to a constant time operation. It might not matter when the size is small, but as the size gets larger or the sample rate increases (or both), this could become important.

Answer (score 1):

Future readers of this post, this is what I ended up with:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

/**
 * @author gobernador
 */
public class RollingAverage {

    private LinkedList<Double> data;
    private double average = 0;
    public static final double EMPTY = Double.NaN;

    public RollingAverage(int size) {
        if (size < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(Integer.toString(size));
        }

        data = new LinkedList<Double>();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            data.add(EMPTY);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adds a data point to the rolling average
     *
     * @param newData
     * @return the new average
     */
    public double addData(double newData) {
        if (newData == EMPTY) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(Double.toString(EMPTY));
        }

        if (data.contains(EMPTY)) {
            data.set(data.indexOf(EMPTY), newData);
        } else {
            data.removeFirst();
            data.addLast(newData);
        }

        fireUpdated();
        return average;
    }

    public void changeSize(int size) {
        if (size == data.size()) {
            return;
        }

        if (size < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(Integer.toString(size));
        }

        while (size < data.size()) {
            data.removeFirst();
        }

        while (size > data.size()) {
            data.addLast(EMPTY);
        }

        fireUpdated();
    }

    protected void fireUpdated() {
        double sum = 0;
        for (double point : data) {
            if (point != EMPTY) {
                sum += point;
            }
        }

        if (data.contains(EMPTY)) {
            average = sum / data.indexOf(EMPTY);
        } else {
            average = sum / data.size();
        }
    }

    public double getAverage() {
        return average;
    }
}
```